# In a quarto book, document language works for html rendering, but not for pdfs

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I am writing a quarto book in Spanish. So I would like, for example, that quarto uses the word "Figura" in Spanish instead of word "Figure" in English when rendering the document.

The `lang` document option does the job when I render a html file:

```
---
title: "Mi título"
lang: es
format: html
---

![Cat](fig.png)
```

but it does not work when I render a pdf:

```
---
title: "Mi título"
lang: es
format: pdf
---

![Cat](fig.png)
```

In the pdf file a figure is referred as "Figure" instead of "Figura".

This problem does not occur when a quarto document is created in a RStudio project. It occurs only for quarto book projects.

I tried to include this code "lang: es" in the _quarto.yml file of the quarto book project, but it produces an error. Any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you are stating.  [See the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGco1.png) I am getting. Can you provide a minimal complete qmd file?

Comment: It seems that the problem only occurs for a document integrated in a quarto book project. When I created a quarto document in a standard RStudio project everything works. I updated the question

Comment: Adding `lang: es` in `_quarto.yaml` works as expected for pdf output for me. [Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPVWx.png) I am getting. Can you include your `_quarto.yml` file and also the error text you are getting?

Comment: Yes, it works! I was placing `lang: es`  in the wrong location within the _quarto.yml file. Thanks!